# Hubtile Animation not smooth after using VisualStateManager.GoToState

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

All,

I am using HubTile from

```
xmlns:toolkit=clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls; assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

<toolkit:HubTile Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                         Margin="0,0,6,6"
                                         Source="/Assets/Categories/events.jpg"
                                         Title="Events"
                                         Name="hubevents"
                                         GroupTag="Sizes"
                                         IsFrozen="True"
                                         Background="#a3bdd3"
                                         Tap="tap_events">
                            </toolkit:HubTile>
```

I would like to start the hubtile animation/transformation from Collapsed state. So I do following in "MainPage_Loaded"

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.hubevents, "Collapsed", true);
```

and it works fine, hubtile shows up in collapsed state. But the problem is that when hubtile goes from "Collapsed" to next state it doesn't animate, it jumps to it without smooth/fluid animation. After this going to other states is normal smooth animation. The first transformation is not fluid. If i don't do GotoState at all then everything works smooth as expected.

Hope this is clear. If there is no fix, any workarounds?

*I am using windows phone sdk 8.0, targeting 7.1 OS.*

Thanks in Advance.